# Reading table header along with the table in word document using python

Tags: python, parsing, ms-word, python-docx

Right now I'm able to read tables and headers separately. Is there a way possible to read table along with it's corresponding header using Python in a word document. Now, I'm using python-docx for reading tables and headers.

Please see the image below for more information about table structure and header. I am not able to read the table header [Table Header & Sub Header] along with the table.

[image: Example table structure]

Comment: It's unclear, what do you want. Where are these tables? How do you read headers and tables separately so far?

Comment: Added the table image.

Answer (score 0):

It's not stated in your question, but I'm supposing your problem is how to iterate over *both* paragraphs and tables in a document, in the order they appear (document order).

This problem and some solutions is discussed in this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40

and this one:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/276

It also appears in this other StackOverflow question:
[Retrieve document content with document structure with python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637211/retrieve-document-content-with-document-structure-with-python-docx)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reference. I will try and comment the result.