# How to retrieve paragraphs, tables and images(inline shapes) by document order in python using docx library

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

The python docx library works with word documents. The below piece of code extracts all paragraphs and tables in **document order** and appends them to a list.

```
def iter_block_items(parent):
"""
Yield each paragraph and table child within *parent*, in document order.
Each returned value is an instance of either Table or Paragraph. *parent*
would most commonly be a reference to a main Document object, but
also works for a _Cell object, which itself can contain paragraphs and tables.
"""
    if isinstance(parent, doctwo):
        parent_elm = parent.element.body
    elif isinstance(parent, _Cell):
        parent_elm = parent._tc
    else:
        raise ValueError("something's not right")
    for child in parent_elm.iterchildren():
        if isinstance(child, CT_P):
            yield Paragraph(child, parent)
        elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):
            yield Table(child, parent)

document_as_list = []
for block in iter_block_items(document):
    if 'text' in str(block):
        document_as_list.append(block.text)
    elif 'table' in str(block):
        document_as_list.append(block)
```

But the above code doesn't extract images from the document.It works for only paragraphs and tables. Each image in the document has a unique 'rID'. I already have the code for extracting the images as a whole from the word document.

But the requirement is that I want to extract the images in document order. It is enough if I atleast append the 'rID' of every image to the list 'document_as_list' as they appear in document order along with the paragraphs and tables. I know we have to manipulate the xml of the word document. But I lack the ability to convert it into code. Can somebody help me out?

I have already gone through the following stackoverflow questions and I'm not able to figure out a good way to do this.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43637211/retrieve-document-content-with-document-structure-with-python-docx)

[Link2](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/276)

Comment: @scanny Can u help me out on this?

Comment: Were you able to identify it? if yes, can you share a probable solution ?

Comment: @dper... Yes you can refer this https://github.com/kmrambo/Python-docx-Reading-paragraphs-tables-and-images-in-document-order-